# Same periodic number is different for a if

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm building a javascript-based web-app;

With a particular data input, a function returns a value of 10/3 = 3.333333333333333 (this is the amound of decimals shown by a colsole.log call); After about 200 lines of code, I have 2 variables (A and B) that contains that value, and I need to check if it is the same value;

The fact is, how is it possible to have an output like this?

```
console.log(A); //3.333333333333333
console.log(B); //3.333333333333333
console.log(A == B) //false
console.log(A-B == 0) //true??
```

I can imagine A == B is false due to how numbers are saved in the memory, but I wish it was a true; and what is really unexplainable to me is how comes the last line output is true?

Comment: I'm ***really*** curious how `A` and `B` get their values. I find it really shocking that `A == B` would be `false` but `A - B == 0` would be true, floating point precision issues or no... For "shocking" read "can't believe without seeing proof." :-)

Comment: Well @T.J. ... I'm writing down some functions to work with geometry, particularly with polygons; The project has grown really fast and now is over 700 lines (I'm not a pro, it is just a hobby), but if you are so interested and have some time to spend, here you can find what I've done so far [link](http://duri.tk/altro/Geom/test.html) (note: it is full of errors, I am going to correct them as soon as I have the time)

Comment: @ duri: What part of that creates the situation above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` (or even `toString`) won't show you the full number down to the bit-by-bit difference. The floating point numbers used in JavaScript (and many other languages) are IEEE-754 double-precision floating point, and they're not perfectly precise, small discrepancies appear and can multiply.

Now, if you literally created `A` and `B` like this:

```
var A = 10 / 3;
var B = 10 / 3;
```

...then both comparisons would be `true` ([proof](http://jsbin.com/yuwaquwu/1)). So apparently you're getting `A` one way, and `B` another, and the fact is that they are ever-so-slightly-different. (I'm quite surprised to hear `A == B` says `false` but `A - B == 0` says `true`, though.)

You'll need to round them to the number of digits you think is appropriate, and compare the rounded result.

Comment: Thanks, this I what I thought, I just needed to be sure... It is just a lot strange even to me

Comment: @duri: How are you getting `A` and `B`?